# Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of Kimetsu no Yaiba anime end in?

Tags: demon-slayer

If you want to keep following the story of Kimetsu no Yaiba after that, you need to know which chapter of the manga the anime ends.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of Kimetsu no Yaiba anime end in?

Comment: you can see that [here](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Story_Arcs#Entertainment_District_Arc). Next arc starts on chapter 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the fandom](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Story_Arcs#Entertainment_District_Arc), the entertainment district arc comprises chapters 70 through 99. The next season will start with chapter 100:

[image]

<sub>*For those going by volume, chapter 98 is where volume 12 begins.*</sub>